# MPLAB IDE 3.55, project title does not appear correctly

Tags: microchip, mplab

I have just updated my MPLAB IDE to v3.55 and when i am opening already compiled project the title of the project doesnt appear[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eLq7.jpg) in Project Pane on left hand side and it just shows questions marks. howvever the project compiles correctly. Any suggestion what i may be doing wrong ?

Comment: MPLABX 3.55 ist pretty old!!! The new one is 5.4.

Comment: Maybe a right click on the project and 'rename

Comment: @Mike i have updtaed to 5.4 and its fine now. thanks